# TinyMCE unnecessarily closing self closing tags -TinyMCE is closing tags like <image> and <rect> How do I stop this?

Tags: svg, tinymce

TinyMCE is closing self closing tags when this is not needed for tags like `<image>` and `<rect>`.  How do I stop this?

```
<div>
   <div id="Test">
     <p>Test response</p>
     <svg viewbox="0 0 240 340"> 
       <g> 
          <image id="svg_1" x="4.1" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Borg_Queen_2372.jpg" y="-49.2"> 
<rect fill="#FF0000" height="43" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" width="150" x="75" y="60"></rect> 
</image>
</g> 
</svg>
</div>
<div id="Reply">reply</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved as seen in this fiddle https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/XZhaab/2
Add this code to your editor initialization section

```
extended_valid_elements: 'svg[*],g[*],image[*],rect[*]',
custom_elements: '~image,~rect',
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('PreInit', function() {
        var shortEndedElements = editor.schema.getShortEndedElements();
        shortEndedElements['image'] = {};
        shortEndedElements['rect'] = {};
    });

}
```